# How to add the Usergroup Access field or tab to a FAL object in TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

I am making a custom template for the 'File Links' element.

In it I want to disable download of some of the files until the frontend user has logged in.

So my problem is the Access tab with the Frontend Usergroup field is not availble on the file objects.

How do I add the access tab?

I have tried making `sys_file_metadata.php` with:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file_metadata', 'access','', 'after:title');
```

Essentially, I want to show a list of all links, but depending on the usergroup some will link to the login page instead of the download.

**Edit:**
I can add the user groups field manually like this:

```
$newFields = [
    'fe_groups' => [
        'label' => 'Usergroup Access',
        'exclude' => true,
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'size' => 5,
            'maxitems' => 20,
            'foreign_table' => 'fe_groups',
        ]
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_metadata', $newFields);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'sys_file_metadata',
    'fe_groups',
    '',
    'after:title'
);
```

However, the only problem is that it does not show up when you debug the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be very simple. To find available properties I was using: `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>`

However this was giving me a shortened list of properties. So when I used `<f:debug>{file.properties}</f:debug>` it expanded that list to include the value I was looking for: `fe_groups`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might not only be the "Access"-tab... FAL does not support FE-groups-handling so far. So only getting the field displayed in the backend will not mean, these are applied, too.

If you really like to protect files, have a look at one of these extensions:

- [FAL Secure Download](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/fal_securedownload)
- [Secure Downloads](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/secure_downloads)

If your use-case only needs a different display and not hard restrictions, maybe you can work with [File collections](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/Collections/Index.html)

Comment: A File collection for restricted files may be all I need. However, the user groups field is not visible there either. Do you know how I can make the user group field available on a file collection?

Comment: Oh... Then it might not be visible there for *not* giving the impression of secured files... I had not proofed that :-/

Comment: Ok, so I guess my question becomes: If I add a new fe_group field manually to sys_file_metadata, is it possible to populate it with the same options/groups as the core field?

Comment: Added the fe_group field manually, but the value is not available on the front end for some reason?